# Parsing specific String to Date

Tags: java, date, parsing

Throughout reading a whole table via Selenium and writing the result to an excel file , I am currently facing a problem formatting/parsing a date `String` in a `Date` object. What I want to archive is the following format:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

The dateString which is retrieved from the table look like this

```
16 APR 2020
```

I tried to use the `SimpleDateFormat` formatter but I am getting a `ParseException`.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16 Apr 2020"
```

Comment: How have you tried it? Can you post the code? Hint: Your desired format is flawed... `m` means minutes and `M` means month.

Comment: Do you have to use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` or can you decide to go the less troublesome way called `java.time`?

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the record: This is how to parse and format a date `String` nowadays with `java.time` (available from Java 8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // the date String
    String dateString = "16 Apr 2020";
    /*
     * which is parsed to a LocalDate using a formatter 
     * with a suitable pattern and a fitting Locale
     * (ENGLISH is a good choice because it is language specific,
     * you could use a country specific one here as well, like US or UK)
     */
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(dateString,
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH));
    /*
     * and which is then printed in a different format 
     * using a formatter with a different pattern
     * (this time no Locale is needed because the format is numeric)
     */
    System.out.println(ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));
}
```

The output of this is

```
16-04-2020
```

Comment: @Eltomon, FYI, if date is incorrect then it won't fail. For instance `31 Apr 2020` will print `30-Apr-2020`. If you use the `SimpleDateFormat` then same value will be printed as `01-May-2020`

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, thanks... this example is better wtth a `Locale` at the formatter that is used for parsing.

Answer (score 2):

do the following

```
     Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse("16 aug 2020");
     System.out.println(date);
```

**output**
 Sun Aug 16 00:00:00 PDT 2020

The reason you're getting error is that `dd-mm-yyyy` does not match "16 aug 2020"
there not hyphens in the later and there are three letters for month and mm represents only two , `dd-mm-yyyy` is kind of regular expression which should match the string to be parsed

Comment: I think it should be triple M. 
`new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")`

Comment: you're right , thanks , i was testing it with 2 M's then forgot to put it back, BTW there is pasing error in 2 M's

Comment: Correct answer, but IMHO we shouldn’t help people use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @OleV.V.  agreed, but i did't know if he had java 8 , and i was a help for something he might already knew , he should learn time package on his own